# BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Facebook

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I see BigQuery Transfer service support "Double Click, AdWords, youtube and etc".

May I know is there any plan to add "Facebook" as well. If yes, may I know the time frame?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, it's about the release schedule of a software library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about a free tool to do this but I see 2 options to do it:

1) **Write it yourself**:

Using the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/) (raw API calls) or one of the [SDKs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks) (provided by Facebook or third-party) to get the data, and then use the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/) or one of the [BigQuery SDKs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) to load the data into BigQuery.

2) **Use a tool (not free)**:

I recently came across a tool called [Matillion](https://www.matillion.com) that has loads of connectors to get data into BigQuery and transform it there. One of the connectors is Facebook. Some more info (for their Redshift product) can be found [here](https://www.matillion.com/etl-for-redshift/integrations/facebook/), but the same functionality is there in their product for BigQuery (which is quite new).

Answer (score 2):

Facebook is not supported by BigQuery Data Transfer Service right now, but it is under consideration. Probably the best would be to [open new Feature Request under BigQuery Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) to let other people to upvote this request.

Comment: May I know why Data Transfer tab is not appearing by default. Why need to request to enable the tab. Just curious to know. How good it is to use this Data Transfer option in the production environment. We have a requirement to pull the data from "AdWords" and "DoubleClick" data stream and push to BigQuery on daily basis. Initially thought I need to write a python code and schedule in App Engine, but when I was researching I found this option but still in Beta so have questions on how to proceed.

Comment: BigQuery Data Transfer Service is still in private Beta, hence it doesn't show up by default. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-service-overview has overview and https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfOFHZCkhHpFyLJmHhq5r9Q1fUy5tj9lefJ1Nt2FtSVKBSCJw/viewform?c=0&w=1 has instructions how to enroll into Beta program.

Comment: Got It. How good it is to use this in production environment to pull the data from "AdWords" and "DoubleClick"

Comment: It is officially still in Beta, but if you purchase support package, you will get support from Google Cloud Support for this product.